# Visual studio Solution Explorer; adding a new filter vs a new folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I come from a c# background and am learning VC++. In c# we only had "Add a new folder" and no such thing as "Add new Filter". In VC++ we can add a new folder OR a new filter.

What are the reasons for the filter? Is it just to help with linking later on when combining projects so you only have to add one "Additional include Directory" instead of one for each folder while keeping your solution explorer tidy with various filters? What was the main reason MS created the Filter concept in the solution explorer?

What's the best practice (or consensus) out there, do you like to separate code files into folders or filters? Why?